# I want to ask a question that I deleted is that possible?

Tags: feature-request, support

I deleted a question on Stack Overflow and after a while I wanted to post the same question. Is there place where I can find the deleted questions or are the questions deleted from the database?

Isn't there some sort of a wastepaper basket?

Comment: Why did you delete it? If you deleted it once, why will you not delete it again?

Comment: You can't see your deleted questions unfortunately, but they are still there for the 10k users.

Comment: @Oded, i tought it was a duplicate but after i deleted it i saw it wasn't a duplicate

Comment: Which question was it? I see 4 deleted questions on your profile.

Comment: @Oded the last one, about postgresql , i tought it was a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579957/postgresql-left-outer-join-syntax

Comment: I have undeleted the question for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only see your deleted questions if you have [10k+ reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools).

But even if you have enough reputation, you can't find a link to your deleted posts on Stack Overflow anywhere. There is a [feature request for that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted) but that one got declined.

Answer (score 3):

If you deleted a question and want to undelete it, you can do so by *asking a moderator for help.* Flag any of your posts with a custom flag reason, and make clear what you're asking the moderator to do (to undelete a post you deleted), and describe the post as best as possible so they can find it.

(Moderators can see deleted posts like 10k users, but they have the additional ability to *search deleted posts*. And they can undelete a post with a single undelete vote.)